# dplyr mutate not applying to individual element of field

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do a calculation using an home made function inside a `mutate` call and it's not doing what I'm expecting it to do.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
#the data
dd <- structure(list(fire_zone = c("ET", "EJB", "WJB"), base_med = c(1, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# my home made function
med2lambda <- function(med) polyroot(c(-0.02, 1/3 - med, 1)) %>% {suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))} %>% max
```

So, what my function does is to estimate the lambda associated to the median from a Poisson distribution by calculating the root of a quadratic function. Despite the long explanation, it's actually pretty basic:

```
med2lambda(1)
[1] 0.695426
med2lambda(2)
[1] 1.678581
```

Now, I want to use it in a `mutate` call to add a field giving the lambda associated to each median in the table:

```
dd %>% mutate(lambda = med2lambda(base_med), log = log(base_med))
fire_zone base_med   lambda       log
1        ET        1 2.128966 0.0000000
2       EJB        1 2.128966 0.0000000
3       WJB        2 2.128966 0.6931472
```

The result is wrong, mutate actually gives me the results of:

```
med2lambda(dd$base_med)
[1] 2.128966
```

I've added the `log` call in the `mutate` to give an idea of what it should do.  `log` works great in the `mutate` as it is called element by element.

Any insight about this behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, I think you need to add `group_by(base_med) %>%` before your `mutate` call.

Comment: not really, I don't want the ones to be grouped togethere, I really just want my function to work the same way as the `log` function for example

Comment: @Bastien `log` is vectorised, your function `med2lambda` is not. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow `med2lambda` to take vectors instead of scalars.

One possibility is to use `Vectorize`:

```
med2lambda.vectorised <- Vectorize(med2lambda)
dd %>% mutate(lambda = med2lambda.vectorised(base_med), log = log(base_med))
#  fire_zone base_med   lambda       log
#1        ET        1 0.695426 0.0000000
#2       EJB        1 0.695426 0.0000000
#3       WJB        2 1.678581 0.6931472
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite `med2lambda` to take a vector as argument:

```
med2lambda2 <- function(med) sapply(med, function(x)
    polyroot(c(-0.02, 1/3 - x, 1)) %>% {suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.))} %>% max)
dd %>% mutate(lambda = med2lambda2(base_med), log = log(base_med))
#  fire_zone base_med   lambda       log
#1        ET        1 0.695426 0.0000000
#2       EJB        1 0.695426 0.0000000
#3       WJB        2 1.678581 0.6931472
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `Vectorize`.  Seems to to exactly what I need.  Also, how would I rewrite `med2lambda` to take vector as argument, I'm not quite sure I know how to do that?

Comment: @Bastien You could use `sapply` inside `med2lamba2`; I've updated my answer to demonstrate. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
dd %>% 
    mutate(lambda = map_dbl(base_med, med2lambda), log = log(base_med))
```